# Regarding xml stream

Tags: java, xml

I was going through a method an application please advise what it basically do as per my understanding it  reads an xml stream and returns it as a String

```
public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

 protected Object processStream(InputStream inp) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inp);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bufferLength = 0;
    while ((bufferLength = bis.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
      zip.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
      zip.flush();
    }
    zip.close();
    baos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();

  }
```

Comment: The code has nothing to do with XML, unless the _caller_ of `processStream()` is sending in XML. `processStream()` just compresses an input stream to an in-memory byte-array buffer.

Answer (score 0):

it is writing to output stream i.e.compressed data in the GZIP by reading buffer byte by byte until buffer returns null.

but in program buffer is empty

Answer (score 0):

It reads input stream (from a file for example) and writes to an output stream in a zip (compressed) format (precisely compressed data in the GZIP file format)